# scrollTop Broken: Body Height 100%, Overflow Auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, scrolltop

http://jsfiddle.net/o7z1pnfx/

I am working on a website with the following layout:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="main"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the following CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,
body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html {
    overflow:hidden;
}
body {
    overflow:auto;
}
#left,
#main {
    min-height:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

The rest of the CSS isn't really important, but rest assured that I have the floats cleared, etc. The layout looks exactly as I want it to.

The purpose of the provided CSS is to make it so that #left and #main will be at minimum the height of the window, but if either grows larger, the page will grow larger with it. This is working as intended.

The issue is that I need to use the Y scroll position in my JavaScript at some point, but the combination of height:100% and overflow:auto on body are causing body's scrollTop property to  always be 0.

If anybody has a JavaScript alternative or a small CSS change to fix this, that would be great. I would prefer to avoid larger CSS changes, but they still may be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried $(window).scrollTop() ?

Comment: No - this site isn't using jquery. Edit: I just added jquery and tested it, and it returned 0 as well, despite that I was scrolled down the page.

Comment: Can you post the Javascript and create a fiddle with the relevant code or somewhere were we can see that behaviour?

Comment: Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o7z1pnfx/

Just scroll to the bottom and click the button. It will display that the scroll position is 0 (which is obviously incorrect).

Comment: Yup, it is an ugly a$$ bug... And a stupid one too... Y u no use Opera 12.17?

Answer (score 2):

Tested on Firefox and it was not an issue. I believe it is a mistake with Chrome, and am reporting it as such. Don't know a workaround, doubt one exists.

Edit: *sigh*, also seems to be an issue in Safari.

Comment: This is likely a bug in the Webkit engine itself. Probably Opera 15+ will have this bug.

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion. I reported the bug to Chromium and apparently a fix has already been in place since version 30, but is not enabled by default and can only be enabled via chrome://flags

Comment: That is weird... To make a "simple" standard page to work properly, you have to edit definitions? Well, what a great browser!...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my late solution but I just encouter an issue just like you. The point is html tag doesnt like any overflow rule in it. Just remove any overflow from html and put in body and it work

Answer (score 2):

Using just min-height won't break the scroll functions. (only tested in Chrome). 100vh seems to work fine too.

```
body, html {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

or

```
body, html {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you can get around this bug by using `100vh` on the elements you want to always be the height of the window.

See the modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ad8s1Ly6/).

Viewport units arn't perfectly suported but it looks like this will work in [most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Answer (score 0):

Actually @scwcompton, your answer lead me on the right track for a fine workaround. What happens is actually that webkit browsers don't repaint the page for some reason.

Forcing the repaint fixed the issue for me. I added the following code right before I animate the body element :

```
  MLB.BODY = $("#body");
  MLB.BODY.css("display", "none");
  MLB.BODY.height(); // no need to store this anywhere, the reference is enough
  MLB.BODY.css("display", '');


  MLB.BODY.scrollTop(99999);
```